# Adding constraints to Pulp, efficient manner?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, pulp

I am faced with a very large problem due to the number of variables and am unsure of how better to model this problem at the moment.  I want to run this optimization, but its taking too long to even add all the constraints.

Previously this has worked fine, as my problems were much smaller.

Wondering what is the correct way to add this constraint to a pulp problem?

```
for block in blocks:
    for week in weeks:
        for day in days:
            for time in timeslots:
                for room in rooms:
                
                    prob += overtime[block, week, day, time, room] >= 2.5*block_schedule.at[(block, week, day, time),room] - lpSum([assigned[nurse, week, day, time, room] for nurse in nurses])
```

For some context:

blocks 0 - 30, weeks 0 - 5, days 0 - 6, timeslots 96, rooms 24. Thats 2.9M constraints.

Comment: What do you consider to be "too long"?  You are constructing a model with 3M constraints with sums buried in each one...

Comment: PuLP is inherently slow for very large models.

Comment: You might also try the [PyPy](https://www.pypy.org/) JIT-Compiler instead of the standard CPython Python interpreter. PuLP also supports PyPy.

Comment: Are you sure you want to solve a problem with 2.9M constraints though? If it takes long to build, it will probably take a lot longer to solve (if you manage to build it in memory and send it to a solver at all).

Comment: I am trying to find ways to restructure the model and reduce the number of variables / constraints.  Wondering if this is the correct method of adding constraints?  Can anyone point me to some more complicated model examples built with Pulp?